# mat-table angular material data source format

Tags: json, angular, angular-material, datasource, angular-material-table

I am using Angular Material Mat-Table. how to change this data into a mat-table data source format.
can someone help me to change this data as mat-table dataSource?

https://stackblitz.com/angular/jnmrolgdbaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

```
"timelineitems": [
    {
        "1/29/2020": {
            "new_daily_cases": 0,
            "new_daily_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 0,
            "total_recoveries": 0,
            "total_deaths": 0
        },
        "1/30/2020": {
            "new_daily_cases": 1,
            "new_daily_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 1,
            "total_recoveries": 0,
            "total_deaths": 0
        },
        "1/31/2020": {
            "new_daily_cases": 1,
            "new_daily_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 1,
            "total_recoveries": 0,
            "total_deaths": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: how do you want to show the data ?  name  columns and headers

Comment: @programoholic I want data in  this type
 `{position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'}, `

`{ date:1/29/2020 , "new_daily_cases": 1,"new_daily_deaths": 0,             "total_cases": 1,"total_recoveries": 0,"total_deaths": 0},

{  date:1/30/2020 , "new_daily_cases": 1,"new_daily_deaths": 0,"total_cases": 1,             "total_recoveries": 0,"total_deaths": 0},`

Comment: tell in Your data ?

Comment: @programoholic
`{
"date":"1/29/2020",
"new_daily_cases": 0,
"new_daily_deaths": 0,
"total_cases": 0,
"total_recoveries": 0,
"total_deaths": 0
},
{
"date":"1/30/2020",
"new_daily_cases": 1,
"new_daily_deaths": 0,
"total_cases": 1,
"total_recoveries": 0,
"total_deaths": 0
},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way you can merge the array given by you into a iterable Array .

```js
const TIMELINE_ITEMS = [
    {
        "1/29/2020": {
            "new_daily_cases": 0,
            "new_daily_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 0,
            "total_recoveries": 0,
            "total_deaths": 0
        },
        "1/30/2020": {
            "new_daily_cases": 1,
            "new_daily_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 1,
            "total_recoveries": 0,
            "total_deaths": 0
        },
        "1/31/2020": {
            "new_daily_cases": 1,
            "new_daily_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 1,
            "total_recoveries": 0,
            "total_deaths": 0
        }
    }
];


let finalArray = [];
   let data  = TIMELINE_ITEMS[0];
   Object.keys(data).forEach((key)=>{
         let obj = {
           date  : key,
           ...data[key]  
         }
        finalArray.push(obj); 
   });
        console.log(finalArray);
```

Once you have the flat array, set the table `columns` and `datasource` as below :

```
this.displayedColumns = Object.keys(finalArray[0]);
this.dataSource = finalArray;
```

Here is the working stackblitz demo :  [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-89d3u5)

Comment: you can also use the keyvalue pipe, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you use as data

```
data=TIMELINE_ITEMS[0]
```

You can use as source data|keyvalue

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data|keyvalue" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

And yours columns

```
 {{element.key}} 
 {{element.value.new_daily_cases}} 
 {{element.value.new_daily_deaths}}
 ...
```

In this case, which Displayed columns we can use?. Well, you can has a fake displayed columns

```
displayedColumns:string[]=["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
```

if we use the columns as show it above

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-89d3u5-xkxfvr?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html)